# SelectRow in ViewPicker

Tags: objective-c, ios

In viewDidLoad i've this code:

> // Here is always shown the correct string aCapital value one, two, three, four

NSLog(@"capital %@", self.aCapital);

```
if (!self.aCapital) {
  self.aCapital = @"One";
     } else {

if (self.aCapital = @"One") {
    [self.Select selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"One");
    return;
}

if (self.aCapital = @"Two") {
    [self.Select selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Two");
    return;
}

if (self.aCapital = @"Three") {
    [self.Select selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Three");
    return;
}

if (self.aCapital = @"Four") {
    [self.Select selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Four");
    return;
}

     }
```

But the Select PickerView not shows the correct selectRow.
If i delete all that code and in viewDidLoad i simply insert

> [self.Select selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

The correct Three row is shown (and the same for one and two value).
Instead with selectRow:3 is NOT shown Four but One !

Answer (score 1):

This line makes the issue `if (self.aCapital = @"One")` you are assigning the value inside the `if` statement. This expression evaluates `true` always.

You need to compare the values using

```
if (self.aCapital == @"One")
```

or

```
if ([self.aCapital isEqualToString: @"One"])
```

Comment: Thanks both. Now the values are passed ok but the Select ViewPicker continues not to show the correct row, why ?

Comment: Yes, sure. I should add another [self.Select selectRow:(passing here the right row?) inComponent:0 animated:NO]; at the end of the if conditions (don't think so).

Comment: no, there is no need of this, I think there is some issues with your code, what is `aCapital` and what is `Select` ?

Comment: aCapital is a NSString variable. Select is the ViewPicker.

Comment: I think in the `viewDidLoad` `if (!self.aCapital)` this condition evaluates true. Hence it won't work further selection, because you wrote it on the else part

Comment: I completely delete the if(!self.aCapital) condition. I'm sure that the aCapital value is passed correctly (from another view). In fact i insert NSLog and i see the value passed. But, unfortunately the picker continues to stay on "One" value.

Comment: I've found what happens but don't know the solution :) while the aCapital Value is passed here: NSLog(@"capital %@", self.aCapital); i see that in the four if statements no NsLog is triggered. why ???

Comment: @Fabrizio: which means the if condition is evaluating false, please check the value, is there any space or character changes and is there 4 rows ?

Comment: if ([self.aCapital isEqualToString: @"One"]) That works ! == no ! I only have residual issue on the Four item (it's shown instead One)

Answer (score 0):

You actually assigning a value not comparing. You should type:

```
if (self.aCapital == @"One") {
    [self.Select selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"One");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks both. Now the values are passed ok but the Select ViewPicker continues not to show the correct row, why ?